# Value not going outside async function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function and use the value from that function to the global variable. The problem is value is not going outside. I am kinda not so good in javascript. I don't know if i wrote the function correctly.

```
async function leader(platformName){

let fullUrl = getUrlPrefix(platformName) + "createsessionjson/" + devKey + "/" + sig('createsession') + "/" + timestamp;


        const response = await fetch(fullUrl, { method: 'GET' });
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
        console.log(json.session_id);
        return (json.session_id);



}
var session1 = ''; 

export async function leaderboard (platformName) {

    var session =  await leader(platformName);
    console.log("Session" + ":" + " " + session);
    session1 = session;
}

export function leaderboardsession (platformName) {

    console.log("Global session" + ":" + " " + session1);
    let fullUrl1 =  getUrlPrefix(platformName) + "getleagueleaderboardjson/" + devKey + "/" + sig('getleagueleaderboard') + "/" + session1 + "/" + timestamp + "/" + 428 + "/" + 27 + "/" + 2;

    console.log("this is inner url ->" + "\n" + fullUrl1);
    return (fetch(fullUrl1, { method: 'GET' }))

        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();

        });

}
```

[Output i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyipr.png)

Here the global session is empty. I want to call leaderboard() one time, store the session in global session variable and use the global session in leaderboardsession() [as many time i call leaderboardsession()].

How do i store that ?

Comment: how and where and when are you calling the leaderboard function? The example is incomplete

Comment: `return session` from leaderboard, then do `var session1 = leaderboard();` and finally `await session1` whenever you want to use it

Comment: @JonasWilms for that, leaderboard() would have to return a value, surely?

Comment: But how do i store the session to session1 ? bit confused

Comment: @Cinah you don't seem to ever be calling the leaderboard() function. It won't populate if you don't call the function. See my first comment

Comment: Thanks @Jonas Wilms . I am getting the global session1 value. I have a small question. Is it actually storing the session value in session1 when doing "var session1 = leaderboard();" OR i am calling session1 "await session1" everytime whenever i want to use, which in turn will call leaderboard(); Could u plz clarify this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var session1;

 async function leaderboard() {
   // something async that is finisjed *somewhen*
   session1 = session;
 }

 leaderboard(); // I assume you planned to call it
```

The code above is bad as it assumes that `leaderboard()` finishes before you use `session1` elsewhere and that is quite error prone as `leaderboard()` might take longer as you assume it would, and then `session1` stays `undefined` and causes trouble as the functions relying on it fail.

Therefore some small rules that you should always (/mostly/sometimes) follow to prevent sich things:

1) Don't use global variables.
2) And never mutate them from inside an async function.

Instead `return` the results from the async function. Calling the function will return a Promise, so if you do:

```
 async function leaderboard() {
   //...
   return session;
 }

 var session1 = leaderboard();
```

you immeadiately start executing leaderboard, and that will be executec only once (as you just call it once), but `session1` contains a promise, so you always know if leaderboard() is already done. If you do

```
 await session1
```

inside another async function, that async function will stop there until the execution of leaderboard was done. That way, if `leaderboard()` wasn't done yet, all functions relying on it will wait, if it finished execution already awaiting it will proceed immeadiately.